# C++ how to split strings in a text file

Tags: c++, string, split

I have a text file, and want to extract it in two text files by splitting the strings in the file.

The text file look like this:

List.txt

```
A00.0 - Description
A01 - Some other text here
B07.2 - Lorem ipsum
..........................
```

I want to extract the part "A00.0" in a new text file, and the description part in another text file.

Code.txt

```
A00.0
A01
B07.2
```

Desc.txt

```
Description
Some other text here
Lorem Ipsum
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Open an input stream and two output streams. Read a line from the input stream. Split the input line. Write the first have to stream one and the second have to stream two. Repeat read/split/write until complete. There are questions and answers on SO that already address each step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to really "split" it.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream listfile;
    listfile.open("List.txt");
    ofstream codefile;
    codefile.open("Code.txt");
    ofstream descfile;
    descfile.open("Desc.txt");

    string temp;
    while(listfile>>temp)
    {
        codefile<<temp<<endl;
        listfile>>temp;
        getline(listfile, temp);
        temp=temp.substr(1, temp.length() - 1);
        descfile<<temp<<endl;
    }

    listfile.close();
    codefile.close();
    descfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for an STL way of doing this, and since you know in advance the separator character and its position, you could do it as follows:

```
std::ifstream file("text.txt");
if (!file)
    return ERROR; // Error handling

std::string line;
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string first, second;
    iss >> first;
    iss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '-');
    iss >> second;
    std::cout << first << " * " << second << std::endl; // Do whatever you want
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/MePUkR)</kbd>

Each one of these steps could have been addressed with a single research on SO for "file open c++", "text delimiter read" and similar keywords.

Answer (score 0):

1. use getline() to read each line from your src file.
   as:
   `while( getline(srcfile,str) )
   {
   //todo::
   }`
2. use find_first_of() to split this line string.
   as: 
   `string _token_str = " - ";
   size_t _pos = str.find_first_of(_token_str);
   if ( std::string::npos!=_pos )
   {
   // head: A00.0
   string _head = str.substr(0,_pos);
   // tail: Description
   string _tail = str.substr(_pos+_token_str.size());
   }`
3. output string _head and _tail to your files;